# Meteor, react, this.props.children shows nothing

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I'm using Meteor js and now trying to start using React.

My problem:
Only empty space between 'Hello' tags (it should be h1 header 'Test'), what's the problem here?

React.html:

```
<head>
  <title>react</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="hello">
    <Hello>Test</Hello>
  </div>
  <div id="render-target"></div>
</body>
```

App.jsx:

```
MainLayout = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>main content here..</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
Hello = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="hello">
        <h1>{this.props.children}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

If i'm replacing {this.props.children} with any string, all working good.

react.jsx:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    ReactDOM.render(<MainLayout />, document.getElementById("render-target"));
    ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById("hello"));
  });
}
```

I'm have only this three files in my root directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All children components should be rendered by their parent component. In this case, MainLayout is your parent component and Hello is your child component.

React.html:

```
<head>
  <title>react</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="render-target"></div>
</body>
```

App.jsx:

```
MainLayout = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Hello>Test</Hello>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
Hello = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="hello">
        <h1>{this.props.children}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

react.jsx:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    ReactDOM.render(<MainLayout />, document.getElementById("render-target"));
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or closer to your original code, you just need to specify the children in the tag you're **rendering**, not the host html you're replacing:

react.jsx

```
...
ReactDOM.render(<Hello>Test</Hello>, document.getElementById("hello"));
...
```